# How to change the Auto Code Completion pop up window colors in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

I know there are some similar questions out there but still no answer and it is something pretty annoying for some of us.

Introduction:
When we are typing code in Android Studio, we have the (I am not sure if it's the correct component name) Auto Code Completion pop up window, this is how I call it.
Here an image of the mentioned pop up window:

[image]

Problem:
When you use a dark theme (e.g. Darcula), and this window pops up, you can barely see the code preselected and you have to force your eyes to see where is the code pre-selection/selected. I have tried for quite a long time to look how to change the pre-selected code color but with no success.

Does somebody know how to change this colors, please?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with Theme Plugins?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).